# Random number that divides by 5

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomx = random.Next(0, 240);
```

This is the way I get my random number, from 0 to 240, how can get only integrals that divide with 5? (0 included)

0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 .. 240

Comment: What, no-one with the `x = 1; while ((x % 5) > 0) x = random.Next(0,240);` solution?  :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: No! You're the first!

Comment: @paxdiablo: Theoretically it's possible that your code will be pending in the loop for a loooong time.

Comment: This question has been asked before, please search (or learn to do so).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this:

```
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(0, 48) * 5;
```

Or, if you need 240 included, as your list indicates:

```
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(0, 49) * 5;
```

Comment: Thank you... can't believe the answer was so simple.

Comment: +1, but I think if you want 240 to be included, your number should be 49 rather than 48. It's _exclusive_ at the top end so the highest number you'll get now is 47x5 or 235. Fixed that for you.

Comment: I prefer the self-documenting: `random.Next(0,240/5 +1) * 5` I'm too lazy to calculate 49 myself and this way it's more clear what the 49 actually mean (and constant expressions will likely be compiled to a single number anyway)

Comment: @slebetman: that's no more self documenting than the single number version. If you want to be self-documenting, replace the numbers with constant names.

Comment: @Lie: It is more self documenting, just not as self documenting a constant name. And if you do decide to declare it as a constant please don't do:`#define RANGE 49` instead do it properly as: `#define RANGE 240/5 +1`.

Comment: @slebetman: Call me extremists, but unless on a Quick 'n' Dirty scripts (and I do sometimes write production code QnD), I personally prefer to do it as `const int SCREEN_SIZE = 240`, `const int CELL_SIZE = 5`, and create a function: `void random_cell(int max, int skip) { return random.Next(max / skip + 1) * skip; }`, which gets called with `random_cell(SCREEN_SIZE, CELL_SIZE)`, for example, if the purpose of the function is to pick a random 5x5 block of area (I'm Ok too with the version using `#define` and macro function in certain cases, though I prefer const and implicit compiler inlining).

Comment: @Lie: Yes, that's the way to go. My point is don't make 49 a magic number. Just because someone gives it a name does not make it non-magic. 240 on the other hand is not a magic number because it actually has meaning ie:SCREEN_SIZE. Or more appropriately REGION_SIZE.

Comment: The ones I love are `#define FORTY_NINE 49`. I always get a good chuckle out of those, trying to figure out just _how_ they came to the conclusion it was more readable. Or perhaps that was just in case the value of `FORTY_NINE` ever changes :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's one (very bad, hence the community wiki) way to do it:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomx = 1;
while ((randomx % 5) > 0)
    randomx = random.Next (0,240);
```

:-)

Feel free to downvote this answer into oblivion. It's really just to prevent others from posting it.

Comment: All right. Who the hell upvoted me? This isn't useful at _all!_ Other than as an indicator of what _not_ to do.

Comment: Can't let this answer stay buried!

Comment: Oh well, as least it'll never rise above the accepted answer. I suppose that's something :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomx = random.Next(0, 48) * 5;
```

Comment: let's close this as duplicate :p (I know, it's only a few seconds late)

Answer (score 2):

In [response to paxdiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789431/random-number-that-divides-by-5/4789487#4789487).

**WARNING** *Humor code not very suitable for production environments*

```
public  static IEnumerable<int> RandomGen(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    var random = new Random();
    while (true) yield return random.Next(minValue, maxValue);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> RandomGen(int minValue, int maxValue, params Func<int, bool>[] predicates)
{
    return RandomGen(minValue, maxValue)
        .Where(rnd => predicates.Aggregate(true, (a, pred) => a && pred(rnd)));
}
```

This way you can simply

```
foreach (var x in RandomGen(0, 240, r => (r%5)==0))
{
// use x
}
```

(please don't shoot me)